# Package Cuda 8 not found for PyTorch

Tags: python, installation, pytorch

I am trying to follow the tutorial for chatbots at facebook (https://github.com/facebookresearch/end-to-end-negotiator) and I am stuck here :
conda install pytorch torchvision cuda80 -c soumith
 I managed to get all packages except for cuda80 which is not found. I also tried
conda install magma-cuda80 -c soumith
conda install cuda80 -c soumith 
conda install magma-cuda80 -c pytorch

with no success.
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
  - magma-cuda80

Where can I find the package ? I am on Windows10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Anaconda Prompt and run -

conda install -c peterjc123 pytorch cuda80

OR

conda install -c peterjc123 pytorch cuda90